How to manage state across multiple forms in different components with a single save button in a React-Redux app?
I'm working on an application with a .NET Core backend and a React frontend, utilizing React Hook Form for form management. The frontend is not a single page application.
In one of the pages, I have two separate forms located in different parts of the page. These forms are essentially two sections of the same object that needs to be submitted together with a single "Save" button. My goal is to avoid making two HTTP calls (two for getting the object and two for saving it) for actions related to these forms. Instead, I'm looking to make just one call each for fetching and saving the aggregated object data from both forms.
I've considered using Redux to maintain a single, shared state for both forms, enabling me to aggregate the data when the "Save" button is clicked. However, I'm unsure how to implement this effectively, especially since most examples I've found deal with multi-step forms where each step has its own "Next" or "Save" button. My case is different as I have two parts of a form that need to be saved simultaneously.
Here's what I've thought about so far:
Using Redux to hold the state of both forms.
Somehow aggregating the form data in Redux when the "Save" button is clicked.
Making a single API call to save the aggregated object and another to fetch it.
My questions are:
How can I efficiently manage and aggregate the state of two separate forms located in different components with Redux?
Is there a recommended pattern or best practice for implementing this type of form handling in a React application with Redux?
Any suggestions or insights on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for code examples or conceptual guidance on how to set this up properly.
Thank you in advance for your help!

This is the perfect case for redux. There is no particular pattern to take into consideration, but you could use redux actions on each fields to update specific fields in your redux state. Not too hard but can get convulated if you do not structure your components well. Good Luck!

Thank you for your reply, I see two strategies:

When I push on the button use react to dispatch an event to "ask" to both form they current state and after that I should execute the save event.
I need to keep the form states and the redux state on each field update (how can I do that?). When I push on save I should use the redux state to send my event.


The easiest is to use redux exclusively to keep your state. The onChange function on your input will simply trigger a state change on redux. This way you do not have two states to manage at all times. Simply use the pattern component > action > redux state. Redux state upon update is "sent" to all components using it.
